How to assign a windows drive letter to a Microsoft Remote Desktop shared folder?
The screenshot shows my home directory stephenboesch on the host machine stephenb

I have not been able to figure out how to assign a drive letter / alias to that folder. I have tried subst command but that has not worked . Also have tried right clicking in Explorer but no option to assign a driver letter was presented.  How can an alias/drive letter be assigned to it?
Note: the host machine is on macos.
